# Multiple statements in a single macro

Tags: erlang

I want to define some functions that all look about the same:

```
info(Message) ->
  report(info, Message, #{}, false).
info(Message, Tags) when is_map(Tags) ->
  report(info, Message, Tags, false);
info(Message, Flush) ->
  report(info, Message, #{}, Flush).
info(Message, Tags, Flush) ->
  report(info, Message, Tags, Flush).
warn(Message) ->
  ...
error(Message) ->
  ...
```

I can make this a little nicer by defining 3 macros:

```
-define(MK2(Level), 
        Level(Message) -> 
          report(Level, Message, #{}, false)
).
-define(MK3(Level), 
        Level(Message, Tags) when is_map(Tags) ->
          report(Level, Message, Tags, false);
        Level(Message, Flush) ->
          report(Level, Message, #{}, Flush)
).
-define(MK4(Level),
        Level(Message, Tags, Flush) ->
          report(Level, Message, Tags, Flush)
).
?MK2(info).
?MK3(info).
?MK4(info).
?MK2(warn).
?MK3(warn).
?MK4(warn).
?MK2(error).
...
```

Is there any way to squish things down further? I want to be able to write something like

```
?MK(info).
?MK(warn).
?MK(error).
```

Comment: You are trying to define three different functions each with three separate clauses. All the clauses in a function MUST be grouped together so you could not have a macro which generates a separate clause for each function. Which is what it looks like you are after.

Comment: I'm trying to generate the code in the top example, which is a 1-clause info/1, a 2-clause info/2, and a 1-clause info/3, in that order. My desired output is valid Erlang, and it's something that could work with C's `#define` that would let me introduce arbitrary text via the preprocessor.

Comment: I get the impression that you would like the `MK` macro to create one info/1 clause, one info/2 clause and one info/3 clause. Remember that info/1, info/2 and info/3 are **different** functions, not one function. The problem here is that the clauses of a function must be grouped together, they are just different parts of the same function, and they cannot be split apart with clauses of other functions in-between. So one expansion of the `MK` macro cannot define clauses of multiple functions which have multiple clauses.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment, because it implies to me that one expansion of the `MK` macro _can_ define multiple functions if they have only one clause, when Hamidreza's answer is that a macro cannot expand to more than one statement. I understand that info/1 and info/2 are unrelated as far as erlc is concerned, but I wished to define a set of functions according to a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocessor like compiler works on dot-terminated token sequences. As both function definition and macro definition are dot-terminated forms, it is not possible to define functions with terminating dot inside a macro, because preprocessor considers the first dot as the end of macro. Also this [thread](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-July/074795.html) in Erlang mailing list could be helpful.

If you are not forced to use macro for it, I suggest to consider other options like using functions or [parse transform](https://github.com/uwiger/parse_trans).